# Error in accessing columns while reading data from sparlyr tibble objects

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr, sparklyr

I'm trying to replicate the basic example of ALS in sparK from this link:

https://rdrr.io/cran/sparklyr/man/ml_als.html

```
movies <- data.frame(
  user   = c(1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0),
  item   = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0),
  rating = c(3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 4)
)
movies_tbl <- sdf_copy_to(sc, movies)

model <- ml_als(movies_tbl, rating ~ user + item)

ml_predict(model, movies_tbl)

ml_recommend(model, type = "item", 1)
```

This code works for me without issues, the problem is that I'm not able to manipulate
the values in the prediction table which has the following format:

```
prediction = ml_recommend(model, type = "item", 1)


> prediction
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 4]
   user recommendations  item rating
  <int> <list>          <int>  <dbl>
1     1 <list [2]>          2   3.98
2     2 <list [2]>          2   4.86
3     0 <list [2]>          0   3.88
```

I´m not able to select columns, for which I get a null response

```
> prediction$prediction
NULL
```

Nor to filter them:

```
> prediction %>%
+   select  (user)
Error in select(., user) : object 'user' not found
```

I´m not even able to read the data in this way from the original dataframe:

```
movies_tbl %>%
  select  (user)
```

This returns the same error as above.

Comment: `prediction %>% select(user)` and `movies_tbl %>% select(user)` works for me. Did you correctly do `sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")` and load dplyr?

Answer (score 0):

When using Spark from R, you can use (1) SQL through e.g. the DBI package, or (2) the dplyr package. You cannot use base R functions, like subsetting with `$`.

```
# Using DBI
dbGetQuery(sc, "SELECT count(*) FROM movies")
  count(1)
1        6

# Using dplyr
select(prediction, user)
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 1]
   user
  <int>
1     2
2     0
3     1
```

To get data back into R, use the `collect()` function available in sparklyr.